# Webhook for google docs add on using google app script

Tags: google-apps-script

Is it possible to get a webhook response using google app script for google docs add on?

When ever i was searching for webhook response i am getting result for google sheet add on response. I want to call another API and want to received it response using webhook.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.